# Como agendar uma tarefa e executar somente uma vez independente do número de instâncias?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduler

Minha aplicação conta com um método agendado para executar a cada 5 minutos com o `@Scheduled` do *Spring*, porém gostaria de subir mais de uma instância da aplicação e que essa tarefa não fosse executada mais de uma vez independente do número de instâncias.

**Classe Principal**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SchedulingApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.application.name", "scheduling-application");
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulingApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Tarefa Agendada**

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
public void searchAndSend() {
    // FAZ UMA BUSCA E MANDA PRA FILA
}
```

Da forma que está, se eu subir duas instâncias a tarefa de busca e envio para a fila será executada duas vezes por minuto. Se eu subir três, será três por minuto. Como faço para que essa tarefa execute somente uma vez independente do número de instâncias?

Comment: Você pode utilizar a estratégia de setar uma propriedade na inicialização da sua instância, para apenas uma delas ter a propriedade para ativar o schedule da sua atividade. Porém, o mecanismo de schedule deverá ser feito manualmente.

Comment: Caso precise de ajuda posso ajudar na implementação

Comment: Interessante. Podemos considerar isso uma gambiarra?! Hahahaha

Comment: Acredito que não, até porque a propriedade sera setada igual voce fez ali com o `spring.application.name`, mas na hora de inicializar o jar ou o servidor vai informar nos parâmetros de inicialização `-Dspring.application.name=xpto -Dx.application.scheduler=true` por exemplo, isso ja elimina a primeira linha do seu método

Comment: Baseado na segunda propriedade, voce configura (ou não) o scheduler manualmente

Comment: conseguiu fazer?

Comment: Eu fiz usando uma solução chamada ShedLock

Comment: Entendi, na verdade a solução então ficou um pouco diferente da pergunta, você mantem todas as instâncias executando o scheduler sempre, mas, apenas uma por vez.

Comment: A função com o scheduler existe em todas as instâncias. Qual instância vai executar a função não importa, contanto que ela execute apenas uma vez. Envie o email apenas uma vez por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tudo bem?

Para tarefas distribuídas é recomendado que você consiga ter alguma informação onde todas as instâncias do seu Cluster tenha acesso.

**Algumas estratégias podem ser usadas como:**

Trabalhar com um componente/aplicação que realize esse tipo de tarefa de maneira mais profissional, como o Quartz. Segue alguns links:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule

O Quartz pode fazer a gestão de seus Schedulers/Jobs de maneira distribuída e com a possibilidade de acompanhamentos como: Jobs executados, Jobs pausados, Jobs cancelados, Jobs com erro. Além disso.

**Outras alternativas são:**

- Trabalhar com estado da execução distribuída em banco de dados ou em cache distribuído para as aplicações, antes de executar o Job, verificar se alguma instancia já está executando o mesmo;
- Trabalhar com conceitos de Fila usando algum Message Broker como o RabbitMQ ou o ActiveMQ.

Espero ter ajudado.